# Why won't this ajax.done() work?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm writing a "betting" script so-to-speak, and making an automated system.

The bettor will be able to choose to increase the amount or decrease the amount on win or loss.

The PHP script I wrote returns `echo json_encode(array('result' => 'win'));` or 'loss' for a loss.

Why won't the below code update that value of the amount dependent upon the result?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      function updateValuesAuto() {
        // Grab all the value just incase they're needed.
        var multiplier_auto = $('#multiplier_auto').val();
        var percentage_auto = $('#percentage_auto').val();
        var bet_amount_auto = $('#bet_amount_auto').val();
        var profit_amount_auto = $('#profit_amount_auto').val();

            multiplier_auto = (100-1)/percentage_auto;
            profit_amount_auto = (bet_amount_auto*multiplier_auto)-bet_amount_auto;

                $('#multiplier_auto').val(multiplier_auto);
                $('#percentage_auto').val(percentage_auto);
                $('#bet_amount_auto').val(bet_amount_auto);
                $('#profit_amount_auto').val(profit_amount_auto);
      }

      $('#multiplier_auto').keyup(updateValuesAuto);
      $('#percentage_auto').keyup(updateValuesAuto);
      $('#bet_amount_auto').keyup(updateValuesAuto);
      $('#profit_amount_auto').keyup(updateValuesAuto);



var runI   = null;
var $run   =  $('#start');
var $times =  $('#amount_bets');
var $stop =  $('#stop');

$run.on('click', function() {  
  event.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    $stop.attr('disabled', false);
    var ran = 0;
    var val = parseInt($times.val(), 10);
    if(isNaN(val) || val === 0 ) return false;

     runI = setInterval(function() {
        if( ran < val ) {    
          $.ajax({
            url: './requests/bet.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { amount: $('#bet_amount_auto').val(), chance: $('#percentage_auto').val(), multiplier: $('#multiplier_auto').val(), profit: $('#profit_amount_auto').val() },
          }).done(function(result) {
            var result = JSON.parse(result);
              if( result === 'win' ) {
                $('#bet_amount_auto').val() = $('#bet_amount_auto').val() * $('#wini').val();
              }
              else if( result === 'loss' ) {
                $('#bet_amount_auto').val() = $('#bet_amount_auto').val() * $('#lossi').val();
              }

              ran++;
          });
        }

        else {
           clearInterval(runI);
           $run.attr('disabled', false);
        }
    }, 500);
});

$stop.on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    clearInterval(runI);
    $run.attr('disabled', false);
});

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about `if(result.result=== 'win')`

Comment: @undone I'm pretty sure this should be an answer.

Comment: I did that and I'm getting errors on the lines in the if and else if statements Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Answer (score 0):

You may want to trim down the code to the specifics of the problem if the answer does not help, but would behoove you to actually look at the data that gets sent back.  It will be:

```
{"result":"win"}
```

So to access the result in the `.done` function, you'd need to use `result.result`.

Additionally, if you are sending JSON back, jQuery may be parsing it automatically and `JSON.parse` may result in an error.  To get jQuery to do this, send the JSON content-type header via PHP:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is `===` because three equals is a strict operator which means value and type must be equal.

In your case it seems you're trying to make sure that result is type of `JSON` and equals to `STRING`

Try double-equals `==` maybe?

**EDIT:**

Oh got that now...

Actually, you can't assign value to the result of a function. So,

Change this:

```
$('#bet_amount_auto').val() = $('#bet_amount_auto').val() * $('#wini').val();
```

to

```
$('#bet_amount_auto').val($('#bet_amount_auto').val() * $('#wini').val());
```

Comment: I did this and put result.result, but it's giving me the error in the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: have you tried to take a look at what's variable result returns? console.log(result)? maybe there's an error with the page that you're requesting

Comment: That's not the issue, it's an issue with $('#bet_amount_auto').val(), but why?  Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment - that's what I assume from the error.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  But one more issue if you could help. :)  It's updating the actual input in HTML, but continues sending the same amount and not the amount * $('#wini').  Why is this and how can I remedy this issue?

Comment: i don't know if it's an issue with ajax cache but if your values are INT try parsing them with `parseInt` `$('#bet_amount_auto').val(parseInt($('#bet_amount_auto').val()) * parseInt($('#wini').val()));`

Comment: you should accept answer as correct if its was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1.You cannot set value to functions (You cannot put functions in the left side of an assignment)

2.`result` is JSON and you need to use `result.result`

```
$.ajax({
            url: './requests/bet.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { amount: $('#bet_amount_auto').val(), chance: $('#percentage_auto').val(), multiplier: $('#multiplier_auto').val(), profit: $('#profit_amount_auto').val() },
          }).done(function(result) {

              if( result.result === 'win' ) {
                $('#bet_amount_auto').val($('#bet_amount_auto').val() * $('#wini').val())   ;
              }
              else if( result.result === 'loss' ) {
                $('#bet_amount_auto').val($('#bet_amount_auto').val() * $('#lossi').val())  ;
              }

              ran++;
          });
```